# What is the minimum "delay" in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I ask this question because I've noticed that sometimes when I use `delay` with a sub-one figure, the delay never occurs. It is as if there was no `delay` line at all.

I can't identify what causes the issue and I can't tell when it will occur. The issue may not even be based on the size of the delay amount. But, I have only ever noticed a nonfunctional delay when the delay value is small.

Is there a minimum `delay` amount that one should not go below when writing AppleScript code?

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Comment: Are you on battery power, by any chance?

Comment: I am not. I am very rarely on battery power. All of the times that I have observed a malfunctioning `delay` occurred when my computer was plugged into an outlet.

Comment: OK, I was thinking maybe it had to do with Timer Coalescing, introduced in Mavericks. That feature is only active while on battery power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the AppleScript documentation for the `delay` *command* it says "*the number may be fractional, such as 0.5 to delay half a second*" yet doesn't specify a stated minimum time interval, however there is an interesting discussion statement at the end of the documentation for the `delay` *command* which accounts for the timing not being accurate.

From the AppleScript documentation for the [`delay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command*:

> delay does not make any guarantees about the actual length of the delay, and it cannot be more precise than 1/60th of a second. delay is not suitable for real-time tasks such as audio-video synchronization.

Comment: I consider 1/60th of a second to be pretty precise; that must not refer to the issue that I'm talking about. If there is no minimum, what would cause the `delay` command to sometimes not do anything? I'm not talking about very small numbers; I've experienced this issue with, e.g., a `delay 0.7` or a `delay 0.5`.

Comment: @rubik's sphere, The very first part states "_delay does not make any guarantees about the actual length of the delay_"!

Comment: I understand. But the issue exclusively occurs when the delay is small. I don't know why that is.